# Firebase auth not work in 2 same projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have 1 project which I have connected to Firebase auth and it works fine. Today I create new project and connected it to new Firebase project and I use the old code from old app and It doesn't work. I try to replace java file, grandle file etc.. and nothing work. If I try create new user it's write "Registration failed" every time... but in second project this code work fine.

Sameone have this problem and tell me how I fix it and why I can't register users?

My working code here (same I use in other project):

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button buttonSignup;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //attaching listener to button
    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void registerUser(){

    //getting email and password from edit texts
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if email and passwords are empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if the email and password are not empty
    //displaying a progress dialog

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //creating a new user
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //calling register method on click
    registerUser();
}

}
```

Thanks for help and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have not used that json file that you need to paste inside app folder.Another reason may be your package name is different.

Change this Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To this:

```
 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I delete my new projects from Firebase console and i create new and wrote the code again and it's work. In my opinion the problem was in json file or something like that.

Now i don't have this bug projects connect to firebase that i can't try your crash report, but in next time when i will have this problem i can try it.

Thanks for help :)